# Reading numbers separated by commas Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, variables, numbers

I have been searching for an anwser but am not successful.
I should make a simple input in html, in which you should write 1digit numbers [0-9] and they should be seperated by commas.

[image: example]

And the other window (JavaScript Application), the user is able to write one "wanted number" which compares the numbers from the HTML input and if it matches with one of them "GREAT" alert and if not alert WRONG.

**This is the JS code. I know i didn't really do much, i just want to know, how to compare the numbers with "var stevilo"**

```
function stisk(){
var stevilo=prompt("Vnesi iskano stevilo");
var seznam=document.vnos.value;
var stevila=document.getElementById("vnos");
document.write(seznam);
}
```

This is the matching HTML if it's any help.

[image: HTML code]

Comment: Isn't `seznam` and even `stevila.value` exactly what you want?

Comment: seznam get's the value from input. But how will it compare if the input was ("2,3,4) and the wanted nunmber is 6?

Comment: You have written, in bold, "i just want to know, how to put the input numbers into a variable". If that is not your question then ask the actual question.

Comment: I corrected my mistake.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So the value would be a string that contains "3,4,7"

The old way of doing it would be to split and than convert each index to a number.

```
var str = "3,4,7";
var nums = str.split(","); // ["3", "4", "7"]
for (var i=0; i<nums.length; i++) {
   nums[i] = parseInt(nums[i], 10);
}
console.log(nums);  //[3, 4, 7]
```

In modern browsers you can just use JSON.parse

```
var str = "3,4,7";
var nums = JSON.parse("[" + str + "]");  
console.log(nums);
```

Now to check to see if a number exists in the array, it is as simple as using indexOf()

```
var guess = 3;
var exixts = nums.indexOf(parseInt(guess,10)) > -1;  //RETURNS -1 if not in array
```